# Python Regular Expressions - Removing Specific Patterns

Tags: python, regex, alphanumeric

I'm trying to use regular expressions to remove specific key codes that are tied to the name of a genre in my dataset. However, what I have so far is getting rid of most of the key-codes but leaving behind some letters and I am not sure why. Upon inspection it seems to mostly be having trouble where there is a 0 with letters following it, for example "/m/0lxr" leaves behind lxr.

If anyone out there knows how I would go about to fix this, please let me know!

This is the code I have so far.

```
def prepare(self, word): 
    word = re.sub(r'//', "", word)
    word = re.sub(r'/\u[0-9][a-z]', "", word)

    word = re.sub(r'/.', "", word) 
    word = re.sub(r'/,', "", word) 
    word = re.sub(r'/!', "", word) 
    word = re.sub(r'/?', "", word) 
    word = re.sub(r'/{', "", word)

    word = re.sub(r"'", "", word)
    word = re.sub(r"//m//[0-9][a-z]+", "", word) 
    word = re.sub(r'[0-9][a-z]+', "", word)
    word = re.sub(r'[a-z][0-9]+', "", word)

    return word
```

Comment: What is your input and desired output?

Comment: Ok, for my input it would be taking in something like for instance "{"/m/0lsxr":"Crime Fiction"}"  and would desire that the output be "Crime Fiction", but at the moment the output is displaying "lsxr Crime Fiction". Just looking for a way to remove that lsxr bit.

Comment: Why not use `(?<=:")[^"]*(?=")`?

Comment: @ctwheels thanks for your response. Can I just ask for clarity how I would implement that into my code? Would it be similar to something like word = re.sub((?<=:")[^"]*(?="),word) ? I am a bit confused :)

Comment: Something like `re.sub(r'(?<=:")[^"]*(?=")', "", word)`

Comment: How about: `re.match('{\".+\":\"(.+)\"}', '{"/m/0lsxr":"Crime Fiction"}').group(1)`

Comment: @LukeSmith it's usually best practice to use `[^"]` inside quotation marks to ensure you don't get a greedy response. For example, try adding another string between the brackets `{"/m/0lsxr":"Crime Fiction", "/m/0lsxr":"Crime Fiction"}`, you'll see what I mean

Comment: @ctwheels yes, I see where you're going.  Don't you need to escape the quotation marks like `[^\"]` though?

Comment: @ctwheels what's your opinion on subbing out all the unneeded text rather than just matching the wanted text?

Comment: @LukeSmith it's not necessary if you're using a different delimiter (such as `'`). It really depends on the content. Seeing as how this is seemingly a json array of values, it may be best to simply grab what is needed. Usually matches are quicker than substitutions anyway, so matching the values we need to grab is most likely the best method.

Comment: update post as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast
s = '{"/m/0lsxr":"Crime Fiction"}'
final_output = ast.literal_eval(s).values()
print(final_output)
```

Output:

```
['Crime Fiction']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
word="/m/0lsxr:Crime Fiction"
re.sub(r'.*:(\w*)',r'\1',word)
```